# GUI in java, private classes for listener not working

Tags: java, user-interface, inner-classes, actionlistener

I am trying to make a GUI in Java, using something along these lines:

```
public class GUIApp
{
    DrawingPanel dp;
    buttonPanel bp;
    ova = Oval;
 public GUIApp()
    {
        JFrame win = new JFrame("Drawing App");
        dp = new DrawingPanel();
        bp = new buttonPanel(this);

    //Settings for panels and frame

        ova = new Oval(100,100,100,100);

      }
      public void setOval(int c){
        //Change color of oval
      }
  }
```

Then in my buttonPanel class I have this:

```
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel
{

    private JButton btnRed, btnGreen, btnBlue;

    public ButtonPanel(GUIApp d)
    {

        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        btnRed = new JButton("Red");
        btnGreen = new JButton("Green");
        btnBlue = new JButton("Blue");

        btnRed.addActionListener(listener);
        btnGreen.addActionListener(listener);
        btnBlue.addActionListener(listener);

        setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3,1);
        add(btnRed,grid);
        add(btnGreen,grid);
        add(btnBlue,grid);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

        public void clickButton(ActionEvent event) {
            Object location = event.getSource();
            if (location == btnRed){
                d.setOval(1);
            }
            else if(location == btnGreen){
                d.setOval(2);
            }
            else if(location == btnBlue){
                d.setOval(3);
        }
        }

}
}
```

But netbeans gives an error for the inner ButtonListener class, and I don't know why. I also don't know how to correctly call the setOval from within that class to the GUIApp class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So we know that you're getting an error... but we don't know what that error is. *Always* say what the error is - otherwise it's like going to the doctor and saying you don't feel very well, but not saying in what way. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you implement `ActionListener` you must define the method [`actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html); you haven't done that in your `ButtonListener` class. You can't name the method anything that you want (as you've done with `clickButton`), so you should just rename your `clickButton` method to `actionPerformed` (and go ahead and add an `@Override` annotation too).

Now in order to call `d.setOval` from within your inner class, `d` must be in scope when the `actionPerformed` method is called. There are a couple ways to achieve this: you could make `d` a member variable of your class, or you could define your `ButtonListener` as an anonymous class.

For example, if you saved `d` as a member variable then your code would look like this:

```
public class ButtonPanel {
 private GUIApp d;

 public ButtonPanel(GUIApp d) {
  this.d = d;
  // The rest of your code here...
 }
}
```

Or, you could use an anonymous class like this:

```
public ButtonPanel(GUIApp d) {
 ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
   Object location = event.getSource();
   if (btnRed.equals(location)) {
    d.setOval(1);
   } else if (btnGreen.equals(location)) {
    d.setOval(2);
   } else if (btnBlue.equals(location)) {
    d.setOval(3);
   }
  }
 };
 // The rest of your constructor code here ...
}
```

**Note:** Notice how I also changed the use of `==` to `equals()` for object equality.

Comment: Also, 'd' doesn't seem to be declared in the listener class

Comment: Thanks for that, but how do I call `d.setOval(c)` from within the inner class?

Comment: `event.getSource()` returns the specific instance of a (in this case) JButton used in the code, so `btnRed == location` would work correctly.

Comment: @Bart K. Yes, you're right it would work correctly in this case, but in the general case `equals` is usually preferred.